# Validating a Zend Framework form on client-side

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I am a reletively newbie to the Zend Framework, I am busy with a simple
application which does not require the entire MVC structure of the framework,
so I have set my include path to see the Zend Framework Library.

So far I have managed to setup a simple login form. But what I am struggling with
now is the form validation does not occur in my form.MY code looks like this:

```
    $form = new Zend_Form();
    $form->setView(new Zend_View())
->setAction('includes/login.php')
->setMethod('post')
->setAttrib('id', 'login');

$username = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('username');
$username->addValidator(new Zend_Validate_Alnum())
->setLabel('username')
->setRequired(true);

$password = new Zend_Form_Element_Password('password');
$password->addValidator('StringLength', false, array(5))
->setLabel('password')
->setRequired(true);

$login = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('login');
$login->setLabel('login');

$form->addElement($username)
    ->addElement($password)
->addElement($login);

echo $form->render();
```

I'm not sure how exactly one would use the validation classes/methods in this instance, does anyone perhaps have a guide and tutorial I could use or maybe point me in the right direction cause I am not sure if what I did is correct ?

ldevstarx

Comment: What do you mean by 'form validation does not occur'? Are there any errors? If you want to validate on client - it is not enough. `Zend_Validate_*` classes are for server side validation.

Answer (score 0):

Could you make your question a little more clear, are you saying that your validation is not working on the client side or the server side ?

If you're trying to get it to work on the Server side You will need to use `$form->isValid(my_post_Data)` in order to validate the form on your controller. But if you're already doing this and you're not being able to get it work then are you getting any error ?

If you already know how to do it on the server side but expecting it to work on client side then it is not enough to get it to validate on the client side. But you could do it easily using simple ajax request without having to write client side validation again. You could consult [this](http://www.zendcasts.com/ajaxify-your-zend_form-validation-with-jquery/2010/04/) . This is very simple and saves you a lot of time.